# Running SQL Server 2005 in Windows Safe Mode

Tags: database, sql-server-2005, windows-vista, restore, safe-mode

My computer has recently crashed and I can only run it in Safe Mode.  I need to back up a SQL server 2005 database and transfer it a computer that works.

Is there anyway to run SQL server 2005 in Windows Vista Safe Mode?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm pretty sure that SQL won't start.

However you can take the MDF, NDF (if any) and LDF files and copy them to another computer, attach them to the SQL Instance on that computer and you will be up and running.

Comment: Thanks - I was able to copy the MDF file from my broken computer and attach to the application that uses it through a db utiltiy provided by the vendor.

Comment: Any tips on how to discover the path to the MDF sql server is using withou running it? I'm having the same problem, but i'm not sure wich .mdf file is the one sql is actually using (i've some old others). Is it in registry or someplace like that?

Comment: The only MDF which is stored is the registry is the path to the master database files.  Everything else is stored in the master database.  You would need to start the SQL Server and query from sys.database_files or sys.master_files to see which physical files are attached to the database.

Comment: If Windows won't boot normally, getting SQL Started is the least of your problems.